The DB_URL configured in the Prisma .env file is unable to parse the DB_URL correctly when the user ID is an email address
The DB_URL configured in the Prisma .env file is unable to parse the URL correctly when the user ID is formatted as an email address.
Here is the configuration in the .env file: I have escaped all special characters, but Prisma is attempting to connect to my email address svc.wkfctcloud.com instead of the server specified in the URL, ebusiness-service-nonprod-ssseeedddkfcxxxx.database.windows.net.
.env file
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://ebusiness-service-nonprod-ssseeedddkfcxxxx.database.windows.net;database=ebusiness-service;user=KFC{}digibusinessxxxxx{}stg{@}svc{.}wkfctcloud{.}com;password=xxxxxxxxxxx;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=false;loginTimeout=300"

I am trying to pull the DB model from the database.
### *(base) kfc0bxxxx@m-lxxxxxxxx admin-portal % sudo npx prisma db pull*

*Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma*
*Environment variables loaded from .env*
*Datasource "db": SQL Server database*

### *✖ Introspecting based on datasource defined in prisma/schema.prisma*

### *Error: Cannot open server "svc.wkfctcloud.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.*

It should actually connect to ebusiness-service-nonprod-ssseeedddkfcxxxx.database.windows.net with the user id: KFC_digibusinessxxxxx_stg@svc.wkfctcloud.com
I have escaped all the characters in the url user=KFC{_}digibusinessxxxxx{_}stg{@}svc{.}wkfctcloud{.}com still prisma is not able to parse the userid and db.
